# What does it mean by "you're doing a really good impression of it" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> "I didn't put my name in that goblet!" said Harry, starting to feel angry.
>
> "Yeah, okay," said Ron in exactly the same skeptical tone as Cedric. "Only you said this morning you'd have done it last night, and no one would've seen you. . . .I'm not stupid, you know."
>
> **"You're doing a really good impression of it,**" Harry snapped.
>
> . . .
>
> Harry ... staring at the dark red velvet curtains, now hiding one of the few people he had been sure would believe him.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Does it mean "you're remembering it very well", but like sarcastically?

Especially I don't understand what "impression" means here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *word* impression in this context means to impersonate something. NOAD says:

> **impression** (*n.*) an imitation of a person or thing, especially one done to entertain : *he did an impression of Frank Sinatra*

So, when Ron says, “I’m not stupid, you know.”

Harry is essentially saying [my paraphrases]:

- You are surely doing a good job of pretending you are stupid.
- You may not be stupid, but you are nevertheless acting like a stupid person.